# Grunt livereload Fatal error: listen EACCES

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I've been spending the latter part of my day learning about how to create my own gruntfile and add the various tasks I want to it. All has gone well so far but I'm trying to add the live reload feature in grunt-contrib-watch and running into some problems.

My localhost is listening to port 9080 so after reading through the documentation https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#optionslivereload

I figured this would make sense?

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
require('jit-grunt')(grunt);
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: ';'
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['*.js', 'scripts/**/*.js'],
        dest: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("dd-mm-yyyy") %> */\n'
      },
      dist: {
        files: {
          'dist/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js': ['<%= concat.dist.dest %>']
        }
      }
    },
    jshint: {
      files: ['gruntfile.js', '*.js', 'scripts/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        // options here to override JSHint defaults
        globals: {
          jQuery: true,
          console: true,
          module: true,
          document: true
        }
      }
    },
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          compress: true,
          yuicompress: true,
          optimization: 2
        },
        files: {
          "css/main.css": "less/*.less" // destination file and source file
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.files %>', 'less/**/*.less', '*.html', 'templates/**/*.html', 'data/**/*.json'],
      tasks: ['jshint', 'less'],
      options: {
        livereload: {
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 9080
        }
      }
    },
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'uglify', 'less', 'watch']);

};
```

I'm getting this error every time I try to save

Reloading watch config...

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
Fatal error: listen EACCES 127.0.0.1:9080

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the full log of the error? `EACCESS` isn't much to go by.

Comment: That is the entire error, I haven't omitted anything

Answer (score 0):

The error was being caused by WAMPServer, I didn't realise that watch creates it's own localhost.

Now I've just got to try and figure out how to get my site to appear on screen.

At the moment all that's being displayed is

{"tinylr":"Welcome","version":"0.2.1"}